# Get-Mailbox How to Export "Notes" Field - Exchange Management Shell

Tags: shell, attributes, exchange-server-2010

I'm wondering on how to export the notes field on the mailbox. See image below.

[image]

I tried using the script below to export all the properties of the mailbox but it seems that it is not listed.

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "ProAV.Aus" | Select-object *
```

I'm working on Exchange 2010.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That field is pulled from Active Directory, not Exchange. Try this cmdlet I got from [TechNet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/12/25/powertip-get-the-notes-field-when-accessing-users-or-groups-in-active-directory/):

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties info
```